# How to add sitemap in Next.js without using any npm packages?

Tags: xml, next.js, sitemap, google-search-console

I have added my sitemap to the Next.js `pages` folder by creating a new file called `sitemap.xml`.

But when I try to access my sitemap by using the `http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml` it throws a 404 page not found error. I need to add my sitemap file URL to Google Search Console. So how am I solving this problem or has any different method to add `sitemap.xml` in Next.js?

`sitemap.xml`

[image]

Next.js Pages Folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Files added under the [`pages` folder](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) are expected to be JavaScript/TypeScript files with the code necessary to generate a page.

To statically serve your `sitemap.xml` file, you should move it to the `public` folder instead.

From the [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) documentation:

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called
> `public` in the root directory.
>
> (...) This folder is also useful for `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, Google
> Site Verification, and any other static files (including `.html`)!